# Problem in build release APK with firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore

Tags: android, firebase, release

I try to build a release version for my APK but there are problems in the build, and this what is shown in my build-out

```html
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.2.0

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

and this is my **code** Module build.gradle

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 3
        versionName "2.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets {
                srcDirs 'src\\main\\assets'
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
        // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0'

    // FireBase Start implementation
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.2.0'/*i think here is problem*/
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:7.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    // FireBase End implementation

    implementation 'com.github.tapadoo:alerter:7.1.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.20'
    implementation 'com.pranavpandey.android:dynamic-toasts:4.0.0'

}
```

and this is project build.gradle

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I try many things to solve it but the problem is still found and if you have notes in my build.gradle alert me and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the [firebase documentation](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/), they also mention adding below implementations

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:$X.Y.Z"

implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$X.Y.Z"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$X.Y.Z"
```